# How do I recover data from a HD?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, formatting, hard-drive-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Today I tried to read an external HD, and it was dead. The only way it could be re-detected by the system (linux) was to format it (now it is FAT).

Although I know it is difficult that I could recover some data, I'd like to try!

**QUESTION**

Can someone recommend a nice software for recovering data? (Explanations would be appreciated, because it is the first time I'd do something like this)

Thank you!

P.D.: My default OS is Ubuntu Linux (12.04)

Comment: Recommendations are [off topic](http://superuser.com/faq) but see [similar questions](http://superuser.com/questions/11160/recover-data-loss-from-accidental-quick-format). Back-ups, Back-ups, Back-ups.

Comment: [This forum can help](http://forum.hddguru.com/) Just search it you find recommendations and non recommendations. Datarecovery is very complciated and cannot be just answered with out proper diagnosis. You could also [just do this...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=data+recovery+software&aq=0&oq=data+recovery+software&sugexp=chrome,mod=7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  or [this](http://superuser.com/search?q=data+recovery)

Comment: OH PS - If you formatted it you just dug a grave for it. Recovering that will be a nightmare and most likley not possible by your self. If it was EXT2 before you just ruined the journal- the thing that could have saved it.. if it was FAT32 before.. you might find fully fragmented files but don't count on much. Ooops

Comment: Thank you guys! I tried with testdisk and as you said **it didn't work**, at least I could play a bit with the recovery tool! Just in case I need it in the future. Cheers.